# A Range object for Java that partially implements `List`

Tags: java, floating-point, interval

I'm writing a neural net which uses a genetic algorithm to adjust the weights. To represent the possible range of "genes" for the GA, I'm passing in a list of bases. Unfortunately, I realized after the fact that there will be a huge possible range of weights for the net, and storing a list of all possible weights would be inefficient (it could potentially get huge).

This sounded like a job for a [Range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), but apparently Java doesn't have one that implements the `List` interface.

I decided to write one as an exercise, and because I will actually need it unless I can find a better way to represent an arbitrary amount of bases of an arbitrary type.

Problems that I'd like help with:

- A lot (most) of the methods from the interface are currently throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`, either because the operation doesn't make sense (`add`ing to the range), or because I couldn't figure out how to properly implement it. Any suggestions on how to implement one of the methods would be appreciated.
- Originally, I allowed for deletions by maintaining a `Set` of deleted elements. While iterating, the iterator would just skip over any elements in the set. This worked until I realized that `get` doesn't take it into consideration. I'd like suggestions how how `get` could be written to allow for a Set of deleted elements.
- Any general comments on how to improve anything.

Range.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Range
        implements  List<Double>,
                    Iterable<Double> {

    private double min;
    private double step;
    private double max;


    public Range(double min, double step, double max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.step = step;
        this.max = max;
    }

    private void unsupportedOperation(String operationName) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Range: Unsupported Operation: " + operationName + "." );
    }

    //Calculates the number at the given index.
    @Override
    public Double get(int index) {
        double val = min + step * index;

        if (val > max) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "Index (" + index + ") out of range: " + this );

        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Double n) {
        unsupportedOperation("add");
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void add(int index, Double n) {
        unsupportedOperation("add");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Double> ns) {
        unsupportedOperation("addAll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Double> ns) {
        unsupportedOperation("addAll");
        return false;
    }

    //This and the next method are slightly ambiguous.
    @Override
    public Double remove(int index) {
        unsupportedOperation("remove");
        return 0D;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        unsupportedOperation("remove");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> ns) {
        unsupportedOperation("removalAll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Double set(int index, Double n) {
        unsupportedOperation("set");
        return 0D;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        Double n = min;
        for (int i = 0; n <= max; n += step, i++) {
            if (n.equals(o)) return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> ns) {
        unsupportedOperation("retainAll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        unsupportedOperation("clear");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        for (Double n : this) {
            if (n.equals(o)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> ns) {
        for (Object n : ns) {
            if (!contains(n)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return (int)Math.ceil( (max - min) / step );
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        List<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (Double n : this) {
            arr.add(n);
        }

        return arr.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arr) {
        unsupportedOperation("Generic toArray");
        return arr;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        for (Double n : this) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Double> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return new Range(get(fromIndex), step, get(toIndex) - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        Double n = min;
        for (int i = 0; n <= max; n += step, i++) {
            if (n.equals(o)) return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Double> listIterator() {
        unsupportedOperation("listIterator");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Double> listIterator(int index) {
        unsupportedOperation("listIterator");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Double> iterator() {
        class RangeIterator
                implements Iterator<Double> {

            double curN = min;

            private double nextNonRemoved() {
                return curN += step;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return curN <= max;
            }

            @Override
            public Double next() {
                double last = curN;

                if (curN > max) throw new NoSuchElementException(
                    "Iterator out of range.");

                curN = nextNonRemoved();

                return last;
            }
        }

        return new RangeIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + min + "," + step + "," + max + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> range = new Range(1, 2, 20);

        for (double n : range) System.out.print(n + ", ");

        System.out.println("\nSize: " + range.size());

        //Should be "4".
        System.out.println(range.lastIndexOf(9D));

        List<Double> sub = range.subList(3, 8);

        for (double n : sub) System.out.print(n + ", ");

        System.out.println("\nSize: " + sub.size());

    }

}
```

Comment: I just realized that since a `Range` won't have duplicates, it should really be  `Set` instead of a `List`. I'll change that later, but it doesn't affect the question.

Comment: While `Set` doesn't have duplicates, it also doesn't have indexable positions (which you appear to be using).  It either contains a value, or it doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelT Good point, I will need to use the `List` interface then `get` is the main use method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A lot (most) of the methods from the interface are currently throwing an UnsupportedOperationException, either because the operation doesn't make sense (adding to the range),

Start with an `AbstractList`, it already throws `UnsupportedOperationException` on any mutating operation. Implementing  an immutable list is fine, there's one general purpose `ImmutableList` in Guava and yours will be a specialized one.

> Originally, I allowed for deletions by maintaining a Set of deleted elements.

Why? [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Immutability is a virtue.

> I'd like suggestions how how get could be written to allow for a Set of deleted elements.

The most efficient implementation would probably use some tree nodes keeping track of the sizes of the subtrees. Pretty complicated.

Something like a `BitSet` to keep track of the non-removed elements would be simpler. Now, I can't find any efficient operation to find out the n-th non-removed element, but it's doable (using a `Long.bitCount` you can check 64 candidates at once.

> Any general comments on how to improve anything.

Keep it immutable, it's a virtue.

> I just realized that since a Range won't have duplicates, it should really be Set instead of a List. I'll change that later, but it doesn't affect the question

Not necessarily. If the order is important, then it's a `List`. If there are no duplicates, then it *may* be a `Set`. The two concepts are incompatible w.r.t. `equals` (which you forgot).

## Review

```
public class Range
        implements  List<Double>,
                    Iterable<Double> {
```

As a `List` is already an `Iterable`, you can remove it.

Collections containing `Double` are a bad idea as testing two doubles for equality is already a bad idea. Due to round-off errors, you'll get tons of strange behavior. Not worth the pain. I'd either work with `Integer`, or trash the whole idea.

```
private double min;
private double step;
private double max;
```

They should be final.

```
private void unsupportedOperation(String operationName) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
        "Range: Unsupported Operation: " + operationName + "." );
}
```

The classical idiom is

```
private UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedOperation(String operationName) {
   ... the same code, no return
}
```

so you can "throw" it like

```
public boolean add(Double n) {
    throw unsupportedOperation("add");
}
```

and save yourself the dummy return.

```
@Override
public Double get(int index) {
    double val = min + step * index;

    if (val > max) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "Index (" + index + ") out of range: " + this );

    return val;
}
```

This is the first method which will fall pray to round-off errors. For something like

```
new Range(0.0, 0.1, 1.0)
```

you may get that it contains 10 or 11 elements. It's deterministic, but from the user's POV it looks random. A representation using `min,` step`, and` size` would be better.

Skipped many throwing methods which can be inherited from `AbstractList`.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    for (Double n : this) {
        if (n.equals(o)) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is correct but slow. Something like

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Double) {
         double d = (Double) o;
         if (min <= d && d <= max) {
             if (((d - min) / step) % 1 == 0) return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

would be much faster for huge ranges, however it'd suffer from *other* rounding issues and therefore be worse. Your `contains` is obviously consistent with `iterator`, but most probably inconsistent with `get`. With floating point, it's not always true that

`min + 3 * step` equals to `min + step + step + step`.

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return (int)Math.ceil( (max - min) / step );
}
```

That's inconsistent with `get`, even without any rounding. Try it with new `new Range(0, 3, 10)`.

```
@Override
public Object[] toArray() {
    List<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (Double n : this) {
        arr.add(n);
    }

    return arr.toArray();
}
```

You know `size`, so you need no `ArrayList`.

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arr) {
    unsupportedOperation("Generic toArray");
    return arr;
}
```

This is wrong. Throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` is allowed for optional operations only, not this one. It can be implemented easily using `Arrays.copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public boolean isEmpty() {
    for (Double n : this) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Correct, but rather inefficient. Returning `size() == 0` would be simpler.

You're missing `equals` and `hashCode`. Note that they're non-trivial because of the `List` interface. For example, `new Range(10, 1, 1)` and `new Range(10, 1, 2)` must be equal as both are empty. They must also be equal to `new ArrayList()`.

## Summary

All in all, it's not bad, it's just that a collection of floating-point values is tricky and -- even if done perfectly -- hardly ever does what's wanted.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I need my weights to be non-integral though. Can you think of any changes that would allow this to work to circumvent the errors? Is `BigDecimal` subject to floating-point errors?

Comment: Maybe I'll store them as `Integer`s, and scale them somehow to make them floating-point if needed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate *Is BigDecimal subject to floating-point errors?* - It can exactly represent some decimal numbers, but you can't feed it with an arbitrary number. +++ Yes, a scaled `Integer` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, and what did you mean "A representation using `min `, `step`, and `size` would be better"? Instead of using `max`, have the user specify the `size`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'd use the three internally. With `(min,step,max)` you create an ambiguity as e.g. `new Range(0, 5, 6)` and `new Range(0, 5, 7)` are equal. With `(min,step,size)`, this won't happen. Just add preconditions `step>0` and `size>0` (no need to represent an empty list, right?).

Comment: Also, the index that is passed can be negative, so you should check that side of the range as well.